# Error in reading csv file

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to read this from .csv file but getting error

```
Items, FactorLoadings

Social Needs (Cronbach's a = 0.695) 

Smartphone allows me to stay connected with those I care about,0.758

I use smartphone to stay connected with friends and family through social networking websites (Twitter, Facebook, MySpace, etc.),0.761

It is easy for me to observe others? happening by using the smartphone,0.701

I use my smartphone to catch up with friends and relative,0.742

Smartphone allows me to transfer photo/audio or other data with whom I want to share,0.577
```

Comment: How are you loading this file into tex? You haven't given any indication, nor said what error you got.

Comment: most csv parsers (latex or not) will fail on the commas in `(Twitter, Facebook, MySpace, etc.)` unless you quote them with `"` or some other means.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There are several ways to import data from a CSV file; please, supply some more information.

Comment: I got it. Can I also add \hline option here

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the TikZ tag I'm assuming that you are using `pgfplotstable` with my crystal ball. Then you need to make sure that the column separators are not used inside the entries or they are covered with brace pairs as David Carlisle noted.

Here is an example (though admittedly I wouldn't use it as is since it needs some cosmetics)

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
Items, FactorLoadings
{Social Needs (Cronbach's a = 0.695)},
{Smartphone allows me to stay connected with those I care about},0.758
{I use smartphone to stay connected with friends and family through social networking websites (Twitter, Facebook, MySpace, etc.)},0.761
{It is easy for me to observe others? happening by using the smartphone},0.701
{I use my smartphone to catch up with friends and relative},0.742
{Smartphone allows me to transfer photo/audio or other data with whom I want to share},0.577
}\mytable


\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
columns/Items/.style={string type,column type=p{.8\textwidth}},
]{\mytable}
```

[image]